# Transfer data to http server using get/post request method

Tags: raspbian

How can I transfer data from raspberry pi zero w to an http server using GET/POST request method.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is a general programming question and thus off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the commandline tool `curl` with the `-X  POST` or `-X GET` option. There are a lot of examples of curl usage online.